# Reset font size , font family and font color

Tags: jquery, fonts, font-size

How can i write a jquery code that font size , font family and font color reset to the default in a phonegap application?
I need to a sample code.

This is my jquery code that i can change the font family in setting:

```
$("#s3").change(function(){
       $(".size").css("font-family",$("#s3").val()); 

   });
```

Now i want to write another jquery code to reset the font family.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: just make a CSS class with those properties set to whatever you need them to be, then toggle that class on your element?

Comment: What you consider the "default"? Why isn't it the default anymore? You'll need to show some basic code of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the the `font-family` to a empty string:

```
$(".size").css("font-family", "");
```